# Combine Android Themes

Tags: android, layout, styles, themes

I am updating my application to use material design, but for some customers, it's still necessary to have the old design, at least for some time. So I am trying to find an easy way to switch between these two designs.

I already made the following style settings (not an exact copy and I know, it can be optimized):

```xml
<style name="Def">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#eeaa00</item>
</style>

<style name="Classic" parent="Def">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#eeeeee</item>
</style>

<style name="Material" parent="Def">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#888888</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonClassic">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_button</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonMaterial" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="ButtonMaterial" />
```

My buton layout xml:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton style="@style/Button" />
```

I'd like to achieve the following:
To change between designs, I set the AndroidManifest application.theme attribute to Classic or Material. This changes the primary color correctly as expected. But it's not possible for me to change the button layout without manually changing the `<style name="Button" parent="ButtonMaterial" />` parent setting to ButtonClassic. Is it possible to add this setting somehow to my Classic and Material themes to change the button layout too?

Answer (score 0):

the best practice for this problem is to create two build variant and in each one customize base theme.
when you want to release your app you can select correct build variant.
also in your developing time you simply can switch between your variants.